# How to correctly apply tint to compose Image?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-image

```
Image(
      painter = painterResource(id = paymentCardLogoId),
      contentDescription = null,
      modifier = Modifier.size(logoSize)
     )
```

So I have a payment card details view and I am trying to display the colored payment card logo which is a drawable but I need to display it as black and white. Above is my initial code which displays colored logo:

[image: visa]

What I am trying to display is:
[image: b and w visa]

When I tried adding `colorFilter` of `ColorFilter.color(Color.Black)`, it just simply came out to be a black rectangle.

I also tried using `colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(ColorMatrix().apply { setToSaturation(0f) })` which gave me:
[image: gray visa]

So is there any way I can get the text "Visa" to be black and the background as white? There are bunch of `blendMode` that can be used but I couldn't find the right one or I am missing something. :(

Comment: The result which you are seeing from `colorFilter` is as expected. According to your image, you can use `colorFilter` only. No any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Icon` composable instead of `Image` as shown in the example:

```
Icon(
    painter = painterResource(id = paymentCardLogoId),
    contentDescription = null,
    tint = Color.Black
)
```

*If this is also not working then you might have to change your image and use image of type .xml, .svg, etc because specifications change will be easy for them.*